# Guidelines to incorporate images within a CSS grid or flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I am new to CSS, and I have played with both flexbox and grid display features. They are both very powerful, and I can easily create simple responsive web layouts.

However, the minute I add images as flex or grid items, the system breaks. Images either overflow their grid area or violates the grid/flex items size rules (ex: 1fr 2fr 1fr). This never happens with text items. I think it is something to do with the original content size. I attempted some of the fixes mentioned on the web (ex:`max-width:100%`, `overflow:hidden` etc.), but I never get it to work.

I am fundamentally missing something and I am looking for a source to describe the right way to incorporate images within CSS grid and flexbox. Basically, I want the images to respect the grid or flex rules regardless of their content size. Is this not possible?

Comment: Pleas provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code

Comment: I intentionally didn't want to add a specific example to understand the general method to do this but I can add an example to help explain it.

Comment: Are you setting your CSS on the <img> element? If you do that, max-width: 100%, or width: 100%, or height: 100% should all work in both flex and grid items.

Comment: P.S. this is a good approach: https://www.zachleat.com/web/fluid-images